# can't access json object from python method

Tags: python, ajax, json, pyramid

I've looked at many answers showing how to access a json in a python method however I can't seem to get mine to work.

Here is my ajax call

```
var data = {
        'customer': customer,
        'custID': custID,
        'date': date,
        'jobNum': jobNum,
        'deviceID': deviceID
    }

//create customer
if (custID === undefined) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:6543/test",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
else {
    //empty
}
```

and here is my python method:

```
@view_config(route_name="test", renderer='templates/main.html')
def new_sheet(request):
    response = request.POST
    myObject = json.loads(response)

    #print myObject["customer"]

    test = "hello"
    return dict(test=test)
```

somewhat new to python so pardon my limited understanding. How can I get my json and access the object properties? all i get in my cmd when i tried print was `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: Why not use `data: data`, and then access each element as a separate POST element?

Comment: @Barmar: that has its limitations. Sending JSON is a perfectly fine goal, especially when you want to send structured data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyramid` has native JSON request support. Set the `contentType` parameter to `application/json` to tell the server that you are sending JSON, preferably with a character set (UTF8):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:6543/test",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

and on the server side use [`request.json_body`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.json_body):

```
@view_config(route_name="test", renderer='templates/main.html')
def new_sheet(request):
    myObject = request.json_body

    print myObject["customer"]

    test = "hello"
    return dict(test=test)
```

Comment: thank you kind sir works like a charm. Would you happen to have a link to a further explanation of the `request.json_body`?

Comment: @john: I included a link to the documentation already; it links to the [narrative documentation on JSON requests](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/webob.html#request-json-body) as well.